# How I separate logic from presentation?

Tags: php, html

Normally I am developing website and coding `PHP` and `HTML` something like this -

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {      
    // Create Table Body
    $html .= "<tr>\n";
    $html .= "  <td>$title</td>\n";
    $html .= "  <td>$date</td>";                            
    $html .= "  <td align='center'>\n";
    $html .= "      <a href='#'>\n";
    $html .= "          <span class='view' title='View This Comment'></span>\n";
    $html .= "      </a>\n";
    $html .= "  </td>\n";                           
    $html .= "  <td class='td_catchall' align='center'>\n";
    $html .= "      <a href='#'>\n";
    $html .= "          <span class='edit' title='Edit This Comment'></span>\n";
    $html .= "      </a>\n";
    $html .= "  </td>\n";                       
    $html .= "  <td align='center'>\n";
    $html .= "      <a href='#'>\n";
    $html .= "          <span class='delete' title='Delete This Comment'></span>\n";
    $html .= "      </a>\n";
    $html .= "  </td>\n";
    $html .= "</tr>\n"; 
}

//Create View Blog Dialog Box 
$viewBlog  = "<div id='dialog-view'>\n";
$viewBlog .= "      <h2>$title</h2>\n";
$viewBlog .= "  <p>$date</p>\n";
$viewBlog .= "  <p>";
$viewBlog .= "          <img src='".UPLOAD_DIR.$userName."/".$image."' />";
$viewBlog .= "      $comment</p>";
$viewBlog .= "</div>\n";
```

But recently I came across to know one of my friend, that is a bad practice of saving the HTML in a PHP variable. And also said I need to separate logic from presentation.

If it is true, can anybody tell me how can I do it?

Any comments would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: There are a lot of MVC frameworks for PHP, you could start by learning how one of those work. As an intermediary step I'd look into Smarty (http://www.smarty.net/) also.

Comment: [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) If these terms are new to you then you should start from the simplest one. I recommend you check [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)

Comment: seperate html from php code by importing php scripts into your html code

Comment: I used to assign long string variables with concatenation much like you're doing above, but then I learned about HereDoc string notation.  Basically, you can have a string assignment that spans multiple lines while still looking nice.  Simply start your variable assignment like this: $string = <<<EOD        then on a separate line at the end of your string assignment, close the "quotes" with EOD; (Note EOD; must be on its own line with nothing ahead of it or behind it on the same line.)  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How I separate logic from presentation?

## Separate it.

Though it is called **business logic** from **presentation logic** separation. You have logic in both layers. The name says it all:

- perform your "logic" first
- then turn to "presentation."

Taking your example it have to be something like this

```
$res  = $stmt->get_result();
$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {      
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

though I would use some more intelligent approach to get data from database,  something like this:

```
$data = $db->getArr("SELECT ...");
```

then repeat all the steps for all the database or other other services interaction. Your goal is to **have all the data ready that business logic have to supply.** Then your business logic ended and you can turn to presentation.

You can tell a good separation from the bad one **if you can easily interchange template engines** (you can't do it with approach from other answer, mind you) - so, particular engine doesn't matter. Let's take a simplest one - PHP

Create a file called `tpl.php` and put this code there

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($data as $row): extract($row); ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$title</td>
    and so on
  </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

then include this file in your business logic file. Or - better - in some higher level template.

You can see a good real life example of the approach in [this topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6359/better-separation-of-programming-and-presentation-logic)

Using such a separation, you can:

1. Use power of good editor that can do syntax highlighting and hinting (though I doubt you are using one).
2. outsource your design to a professional designer.
3. easily change presentation technology from HTML to AJAX.
4. use the same engine for the different sites with different appearances.
5. Implement any number of "themes" or "skins".
6. Stay alive when adding some rich decorations from either HTML, CSS or JS.

While all this is just impossible with your current approach or approach from other answer. The idea is **separation** of matters.

Comment: Read the list at the end of my answer. These are your problems.

Answer (score 11):

I strongly recommend a templating library like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) or [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php). However, the basics would be to use external PHP files as HTML, and use require. Here is a bit of a hacky example:

```
<?php
$comments = array();

while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {     
  $comments[] = $stmt;
}

require 'comments.php';
```

Then in `comments.php`:

```
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment) : ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $comment['title'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $comment['date'] ?></td>                          
  <td align='center'>
      <a href='#'>
          <span class='view' title='View This Comment'></span>
      </a>
  </td>                           
  <td class='td_catchall' align='center'>
      <a href='#'>
          <span class='edit' title='Edit This Comment'></span>
      </a>
  </td>                       
  <td align='center'>
      <a href='#'>
          <span class='delete' title='Delete This Comment'></span>
      </a>
  </td>
</tr> 
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Here, I am adding each comment (or whatever it may be) to an array. Then, I include a file called `comments.php`. Your main file should be mostly PHP and should handle any logic, while `comments.php` should be mostly HTML and only use PHP for presentation (aka looping through an array and echoing out variables).

Your required file has access to all the variables it would have access to if it were inline.

Comment: [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) and [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php) are also solid options.

Comment: Smarty is an overkill. PHP is itself a templating language, IMO.

Comment: +1 for working example, rather than just a library reference.

Comment: I just wish I could skip the output buffer hack in PHP.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Care to share a better way rather than just downvote me?

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt Don't take the troll too seriously.

Comment: Well, my comment talking about heredocs is quite useless after a solution like this one :P

Comment: @YourCommonSense Your comments are pretty useless, I'm not even quite sure what you're trying to say. I was giving the most simple example of separating business logic and presentation logic that I could. I did suggest he use a templating system, which is the ideal solution.

Comment: You don't understand the difference between template engine and the separation in question then.

Comment: @YourCommonSense While your comment wasn't very helpful, your answer was. I've updated mine to incorporate some of your answer.