# Can't get PHP content to print above footer

Tags: php, html, css

Just a quick question. Everything is printing out fine on this page, except the PHP content is printing at the bottom of the page underneath the footer and everything. I want it to be above the footer.

In the code it's positioned to be as such, but it still prints underneath anyway. Is there something I'm missing when it comes to certain objects being printed out?

Here's the section is question (anything marked with a ~ is just hidden information):

```
<section>

<?php
//Retrieving Database
mysql_connect("~", "~", "~") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("~") or die(mysql_error()); 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY game ASC") or die(mysql_error());
    echo '<table>
    <tr><th>TEAM NAME</th><th>GAME</th><th>PLATFORM</th><th>PLAY STYLE</th><th>TIMEZONE</th><th>FOUNDER</th></tr>';
    while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
        echo "<tr>
                <td>".$myrow['team']."</td>
                <td>".$myrow['game']."</td>
                <td>".$myrow['platform']."</td>
                <td>".$myrow['play']."</td>
                <td>".$myrow['timezone']."</td>
                <td>".$myrow['player']."</td>
              </tr>\n";
    }
?>

    <!-- Line Break Design -->
    <hr style="border: 3px outset #595955;" width="100%" size="5">

</section>

<!-- Footer (name, email, etc.) -->
<footer id="footer">
    <img src="images/logo.png" width="80" height="65" alt="Our Logo" class="floatLeft"/>
    <p>Contact Us<br/><a href="~" target="_blank">~</a><br/><a href="~">~</a></p><br/>
</footer>
```

Comment: do you have any css touching this? Or is this it.

Comment: Have a screen of what it looks like ( or some css involved )? Also looks like you're missing a </table>

Comment: Actually, it may be because you are missing the </table> closing tag... that can often just throw stuff wherever in the layout.

Comment: **PROTIPS**: Start using [PHP Alternative Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and also stop [mixing logic with presentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641738/how-i-separate-logic-from-presentation). Further, [move your DB Connection file](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/qt/mysql_connect.htm)

Comment: Can you provide the generated html code? Because it looks like ans HTML/CSS issue.

Comment: Protip: Use PDO instead of mysql_query.

Comment: Thanks guys, never noticed the </table> being missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a problem, you never close your `<table>` after finishing with the looped echo of content.

Add this after your `while` loop:

```
echo "</table>";
```

And it should work nicely. You can see the same thing happening in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PMYGm/), where a closing `</table>` is omitted. (Note the location of the "Hi".)

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.